# Subscribe multiple publish or one in each Meteor.autosubscribe?

Tags: meteor

which is right way to do?

```
Meteor.autosubscribe ->
    session1 = Session.get 'session1'
    session2 = Session.get 'session2'
    session3 = Session.get 'session3'
    Meteor.subscribie 'collection1', session1
    Meteor.subscribie 'collection2', session2
    Meteor.subscribie 'collection3', session3
```

or

```
Meteor.autosubscribe ->
    session1 = Session.get 'session1'
    Meteor.subscribie 'collection1'

Meteor.autosubscribe ->
    session2 = Session.get 'session2'
    Meteor.subscribie 'collection2'

Meteor.autosubscribe ->
    session3 = Session.get 'session3'
    Meteor.subscribie 'collection3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first example will tear all subscribe when 1 Session changes. Its a bad idea.
So the second example will be the preferred way to do this.